# Is it ok to start a sentence with "The"?

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, phrase-request

I often write sentences which start with the word "**The**" like:

> The reference to Michele Foucault is important to understand MA because of three major aspects: …

I do not really like the phrasing and wonder if I use it because of my German background. Hence, my question is: **Is it ok to use "The" at a beginning of a sentence?** If so, is it common or uncommon to use "The" at the beginning of a sentence? Which more elegent sentence structures exist which do not need the article at the beginning?

Comment: The construction is perfectly valid.

Comment: *The* is one of the most common ways to begin a sentence.

Comment: It is often extremely hard for many EFL speakers of certain languages to get a good handle on English *article* usage ("the", "a/an"). In your specific example, the article "the" can't be replaced by the article "a". The use of "*A* reference to Michele" wouldn't work there for that sentence. It's also extremely difficult to fully explain the proper usage of the articles "the" and "a" w.r.t. to when one is appropriate and the other is not. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem in using the definite article to begin the sentence. I mean there's no *rule* I have ever come across that refrains us from doing this.

In fact, as snailboat says, it is one of the most common ways to begin a sentence.

Say...

> **The** answers on this site are really useful! **The** thing I like the most on this site is its format. **The** best thing I could do to improve my English is to ask a question here. **The** native speakers on ELL will answer them precisely. **The** answers they write teach me a lot; (and finally!) **The** comment is getting longer here.

Comment: If you came across such a rule, would you heed it, knowing as you do how English works? ;)